# Counting occurrences without modifying the original order

Tags: r, dataframe

I am currently searching an easy way to count the occurrences without modifying the order of my dates. I have a column of my dataframe with a lot of dates and I want to count the number of occurrences a date appears.

Let's say I have this list :

```
data[,1]
18/12/2015
18/12/2015
18/12/2015
01/01/2016
02/02/2016
02/02/2016
```

I can use the function `table()` to count the number of occurrences like that : `table(data[,1])`

But the result will be shown like this :

```
   Var       freq
01/01/2016    1
02/02/2016    2
18/12/2015    3
```

And I don't want this order, I would want to keep the original order shown above. I was searching for an option which can cancel the ordering of the function but it seems it doesn't exist. (same for function `aggregate()`)

Has someone an idea ?

Comment: You can convert to a factor with levels specified as unique elements in the column and then do `table`

Comment: I think you want ave, which is a wrapper on the replacement function for split

Comment: `library(data.table); dt <- data.table(data); dt[ , .N , by = .(Var) ]`

Comment: library(dplyr); yourdf %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarise(c_freq=n())

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Your function doesn't work, return an error "  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable "

Comment: Replace `Var` by the name of your column of dates!!! Or, your `data.frame` is not really called `data`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are two options.

First I'll create some data:

```
> set.seed(123)
> x <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, TRUE)
> x
 [1] "B" "D" "C" "E" "E" "A" "C" "E" "C" "C"
```

At this point `table(x)` gives the results in sorted order:

```
> table(x)
x
A B C D E 
1 1 4 1 3
```

What @akrun suggested is creating a factor with specified levels, which gets you the order you want:

```
> y <- factor(x, levels=unique(x))
> table(y)
y
B D C E A 
1 1 4 3 1
```

Or, you can also just re-sort the original table according to ranks like this:

```
> table(x)[rank(unique(x))]
x
B D C E A 
1 1 4 3 1
```

Thanks to @lmo, an even more concise way to do this is simply:

```
> table(x)[unique(x)]
x
B D C E A 
1 1 4 3 1
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this method and it works very well. I thought I have done this at the beginning but I think I have failed.

Comment: @lmo shorter and faster :')

Answer (score 6):

```
# Your data
data <- read.table(text="18/12/2015
18/12/2015
18/12/2015
01/01/2016
02/02/2016
02/02/2016")

require(data.table)
dt <- data.table( data )

#  Your data looks like this:
dt
#           V1
#1: 18/12/2015
#2: 18/12/2015
#3: 18/12/2015
#4: 01/01/2016
#5: 02/02/2016

#  The result is this:
dt[ , .N , by = V1 ]
#          V1 N
#1: 18/12/2015 3
#2: 01/01/2016 1
#3: 02/02/2016 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
unique(df %>% 
          group_by(Var) %>% 
          mutate(count = n()))

#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#Groups: V1 [3]

#          V1 count
#      (fctr) (int)
#1 18/12/2015     3
#2 01/01/2016     1
#3 02/02/2016     2
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Var = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("01/01/2016", 
"02/02/2016", "18/12/2015"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

**EDIT**

A simpler way (pointed by @lukeA) is just,

```
library(dplyr)
count(df, Var, sort = TRUE)

#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

#         Var     n
#      (fctr) (int)
#1 18/12/2015     3
#2 02/02/2016     2
#3 01/01/2016     1
```

Comment: I think you can also use `count(df, V1)` when going the `dplyr` way. `count` has a `sort` parameter, which is `FALSE` by default.

Comment: Ahh... yes. I was looking for a `sort` parameter in `table` but didn't find one so assumed that `count` did not have one either :)

Comment: What's `Var` in the last incarnation?

Answer (score 1):

It was a bit tough generating a time test, since not all answers took a `data.table` input.  Here's what I did:

```
sotos <-function(testdat){
#library(dplyr)
return(count(testdat, V1,sort = TRUE))
}

simon <-function(testdat){
#require(data.table)
dt <- data.table( testdat )

return(dt[ , .N , by = V1 ])
}

mrip <-function(x){
return(table(x)[unique(x)])
}

# make a dataset
set.seed(42)
x<-sample(LETTERS[1:15],1e4,TRUE)
x2 <- data.table(x)
colnames(x2) <- 'V1'

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(sotos(x2),simon(x2),mrip(x),times=10)

Unit: microseconds
      expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
 sotos(x2) 2183.645 2256.855 2984.7473 2352.6430 2507.616 8629.209    10
 simon(x2)  770.417  780.338  831.5502  784.7845  846.021 1116.624    10
   mrip(x)  745.101  827.206  844.3107  850.4685  865.863  898.021    10
# compare the answers:
> mrip(x)
x
  N   O   E   M   J   H   L   C   K   G   D   B   I   F   A 
666 676 659 656 669 631 679 734 677 665 592 672 674 654 696 
    > t(simon(x2))
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]  [,10] [,11] [,12]
    V1 "N"   "O"   "E"   "M"   "J"   "H"   "L"   "C"   "K"   "G"   "D"   "B"  
    N  "666" "676" "659" "656" "669" "631" "679" "734" "677" "665" "592" "672"
       [,13] [,14] [,15]
    V1 "I"   "F"   "A"  
    N  "674" "654" "696"
    > t(sotos(x2))
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]  [,10] [,11] [,12]
    V1 "C"   "A"   "L"   "K"   "O"   "I"   "B"   "J"   "N"   "G"   "E"   "M"  
    n  "734" "696" "679" "677" "676" "674" "672" "669" "666" "665" "659" "656"
       [,13] [,14] [,15]
    V1 "F"   "H"   "D"  
    n  "654" "631" "592"
```

### Edit:

Per Frank's comment, I removed the `data.table` call inside `simon`. The new results are

```
Unit: microseconds
      expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 sotos(x2) 2533.274 2708.089 3067.2971 2804.391 2947.218 5598.176    10
 simon(x2)  500.154  518.286  621.3618  577.641  740.995  787.179    10
   mrip(x)  816.942  950.020 1065.2408  969.007 1282.887 1459.755    10
```

Comment: @Frank - check the code at "make a dataset" where I build `x2` from `x`

Comment: @Frank  ooops, sorry 'bout that.   I'll fix and re-run